# Possible conflict between two scripts

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this script which show/hides div's randomly.  But for some reason it's not showing anything when the page is loaded:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('.control').on('click', function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          var field = $(this).data('field');
          $('.hider:visible').fadeOut("slow", function() {
              $('#' + field + '-gallery, #' + field + '-tag').fadeIn("slow");
          });
      });

      var randomIndex = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1) % 5;
      console.log(randomIndex);

      var field = $($('a').get(randomIndex)).data('field');
      $('#' + field + '-gallery, #' + field + '-tag').fadeIn("slow");
  });
```

and I have this one (in the footer):

```
/* jQuery.noConflict() for using the plugin along with other libraries. 
           You can remove it if you won't use other libraries (e.g. prototype, scriptaculous etc.) or 
           if you include jQuery before other libraries in yourdocument's head tag. 
           [more info: http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries] */
        //jQuery.noConflict(); 
        /* calling thumbnailScroller function with options as parameters */
        (function($){
        window.onload=function(){ 
            $("#tS2").thumbnailScroller({ 
                    scrollerType:"clickButtons", 
                    scrollerOrientation:"horizontal", 
                    scrollSpeed:2, 
                    scrollEasing:"easeOutCirc", 
                    scrollEasingAmount:600, 
                    acceleration:10, 
                    scrollSpeed:900, 
                    noScrollCenterSpace:10, 
                    autoScrolling:0, 
                    autoScrollingSpeed:2000, 
                    autoScrollingEasing:"easeInOutQuad", 
                    autoScrollingDelay:500 

            });
        }
        })(jQuery);
```

I noticed that if I enable the jQuery.noConflict in the script in the footer, I get an error in the inspector for the top script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('.control').on('click', function(e) {
Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object Window] is not a function
          e.preventDefault();
```

But if I disable the noConflict in the footer script, there are no errors, but the top script still doesn't work.  Do I need to put another noConflict in the top script, or am I calling it wrong with the $(document).ready?

Comment: Are you loading some other DOM library as well as jQuery? If so, why? Anyway, if so, you can keep `noConflict()`, and change your first line to: `jQuery(document).ready(function($) {`. Notice the `$` as the function parameter.

Comment: @am not i am I do have a jqueryUI library as well that is being called before the top script.

the JqueryUI library is for a slider gallery, which is what is being called in the footer script.  The top (or header since it's in the header) script is so it will show/hide the div's where the slider galleries are contained randomly on page load.

When I look into the inspector, I see in the console that is pulling a number and then referring back to the top script where it's the
console.log(randomIndex)
But nothing is showing on the page in the browser when the page is refreshed.

Comment: Here's what I am trying to accomplish in a very stripped down sense of it:
http://jsfiddle.net/TRQFa/7/

But where the words "gallery" are supposed to be, that where the slider gallery would go for each item.

Comment: I've had this problem many times before. Oddly enough, noConflict has ALWAYS caused conflict for me. As a general rule of thumb, if I'm writing a plugin for my own use, I avoid using names that might be taken by a library so that I can avoid noConflict.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `jQuery`  instead of `$`. And leave the `$` for other library. By this you will not face conflict issue.

Try like this.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
      jQuery('.control').on('click', function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
```